# text align in span tag

Tags: css, c#-4.0, browser

i write a program to show arabic text.
i use two type of font:

1:a font with out Arabs

2:a font with out text

i can change each color separately with this method.i used two span tag with the same id for showing text with arab and text with out arab on each other.
result:[image]

every thins is ok.
but when i change text-align to justify it dont work good and the text goes out.
result:[image]

a part of code:

```
<span class=ThuithQA id=1-0> <font  size=5>بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ (١)</font></span><span class=ThuithE> 
<font color=Red size=5>بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ (١)</font></span><span class=ThuithQA id=1-1> <font  size=5>الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ (٢)</font></span>
```

i wnt to show text justify.

Comment: share your HTML and css plz...so then we will get an idea that where the issue rises..

Comment: If it works ok in the first example, why do you change it?

Comment: There is something essential in your code that was not included in the part of code you posted. The diacritic marks (vowel signs) appear in red, as opposite to blue or black color of base text. How do you achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could Solve my problem with this code:
i put arab and text in a seperate div 
and set div

```
posation:absolute
```

and set body

```
text-align:justify;
```

a part of code

```
<div style=" position:absolute;"> 
<span class=ThuithQA id=1-0> 
<font  size=5>بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ (١)</font> 
</span > 
<span class=ThuithQA id=1-1> 
<font  size=5>الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ (٢)</font> 
</span >  
</div> 

<div style=" position:absolute;"> 
<span class=ThuithE> 
<font color=Red size=5>بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ (١)</font> 
</span > 
<span class=ThuithE> 
<font color=Red size=5>الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ (٢)</font> 
</span > 
</div>
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If every verse is in a separate `span` then set your css as given below:

**EDITED:**

**CSS**

```
span{
    display:block;
    text-align:justify;
    direction: rtl; /* Direction of text right to left */
}
```

See this Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/mSEj9/1/

Comment: I've updated my answer. You may try `direction:rtl` with `text-align-justify`

Comment: i used to span tag with the same id for showing text with arab and text with out arab on each other.every things ok but when i change text align to justify i get a result some thinglike ( shape 2)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show all text justify, you need a wrapper over all span and this styles:

```
.wrapper {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

You can't align text justify in each span, because they havn't text for full line + some simbols

Comment: The point is that by CSS specs, `text-align` applies to block containers only. The concept of justification relates to blocks of texts, not to inline segments of text,

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the spans to display:block or set widths

Answer (score 0):

Try `text-align` to right.

```
span{
  display:block;
  text-align:right;
}
```